# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in reactjs fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch

I'm new in js and js frameworks is there anywhere or any resource to give me full detailed information about fetch and JSON file? any time I think this JSON file is the same as the old one and when I start to show staff in page I get new errors, this specific is undefined (reading 'map') in Reactjs fetch
JSON file structure:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "instantMenu": [
        {
            "title": "Admission",
            "url": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Faculty members",
            "url": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Research",
            "url": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Campus",
            "url": ""
        }
    ],
    "mainMenu": [
        {
            "title": "About",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Presidency",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "University Vice Chancellors",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Faculties",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Departments",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Research and Innovation",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Portals",
            "link": ""
        }
    ],
```

and Reactjs code is:

```
function Header() {
  const [body, fetchbody] = React.useState([]);
  const getData = () => {
        fetch('https://api.example.com/v1/body/en')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          fetchbody(res?.body);
        });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
  const [darkMode,setDarkMode]= React.useState(true);
  return (
    <header>
      <div id="myOverlay">
        <span className="closebtn" onClick={closeSearch()} title="Close Overlay">x</span>
      <div className="overlay-content">
        <form action="action_page.php">
          <input type="text" placeholder="search it" name="search"/>
          <button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div className='topbar'>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <label className="topbar-lable" htmlFor=''>Action:</label>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
          {body['instantMenu'].map((instantMenu) =>  {
              return (
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" aria-current="page" href={instantMenu.url}>{instantMenu.title}</a>
            </li>
               );
              })}
          </ul>
```

I try everything body.map
body.length && body['instantMenu']?.title when I try this, console log gives me Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') please help guys :) I want to learn and master it

Comment: You need to make sure that `body.instantMenu` is accessible before trying to map over it. Since `body` is an empty array by default, you're `body.instantMenu` will be undefined.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1 ) `fetchbody(res?.body);` - `body` doesn't exist on the parsed object in your question. 2) You're initialising state as an array, but the parsed data is an object so you won't be able to check for length, and you won't be able to access an `instantMenu` property on the initial render. You could do `Object.keys(body).length && body.instantMenu` perhaps.

Comment: @Andy bro you gives me what i want thanks for the help body dosen't exist on the parsed object i tought i can use body and then go put it every where, just call the array in it like instantMenu or mainMenu

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the attribute exists since the `fetch` might still be in execution when the page is loaded.
You can do it with conditional rendering:

```
<ul className='navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0'>
  {!body || !body.instantMenu
    ? 'Loading data...'
    : body['instantMenu'].map((instantMenu) => {
        return (
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' aria-current='page' href={instantMenu.url}>
              {instantMenu.title}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
</ul>;
```

Comment: that gives me instantMenu undefined

Comment: Try to check also if `body` has been defined (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
function Header() {
  const [body, fetchbody] = React.useState({instantMenu:[], mainMenu:[]});
  const getData = () => {
        fetch('https://api.example.com/v1/body/en')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          fetchbody(res?.body);
        });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
  const [darkMode,setDarkMode]= React.useState(true);
  return (
    <header>
      <div id="myOverlay">
        <span className="closebtn" onClick={closeSearch()} title="Close Overlay">x</span>
      <div className="overlay-content">
        <form action="action_page.php">
          <input type="text" placeholder="search it" name="search"/>
          <button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div className='topbar'>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <label className="topbar-lable" htmlFor=''>Action:</label>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
          {body['instantMenu'].map((instantMenu) =>  {
              return (
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" aria-current="page" href={instantMenu.url}>{instantMenu.title}</a>
            </li>
               );
              })}
          </ul>
```

Comment: that gives me undefined instantMenu

Comment: You should add some notes/commentary to your answer to explain what you've done. "Try this" is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy! Use this to handle it in proper way:

```
function Header() {
  const [body, fetchbody] = React.useState([]);
  const getData = () => {
        fetch('https://api.example.com/v1/body/en')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          fetchbody(res?.body);
        });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
  const [darkMode,setDarkMode]= React.useState(true);
  return (
    <header>
      <div id="myOverlay">
        <span className="closebtn" onClick={closeSearch()} title="Close Overlay">x</span>
      <div className="overlay-content">
        <form action="action_page.php">
          <input type="text" placeholder="search it" name="search"/>
          <button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div className='topbar'>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <label className="topbar-lable" htmlFor=''>Action:</label>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-lg-0">
          {body['instantMenu'] ? body['instantMenu'].map((instantMenu) =>  {
              return (
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" aria-current="page" href={instantMenu.url}>{instantMenu.title}</a>
            </li>
               );
              }) : <li>-- Error in Data Fetch! --</li>}
          </ul>
```

the change i have mentioned in your code will at least not crash the view and give you hint what is the issue about!. Also this might not be the proper way to show error in menu but you must at least get hint how to do it for your own need.

I looked at your code more thoroughly!, I found you are initialising state with [] it should be {} instead!!!

Comment: this gives me Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instantMenu')

Comment: I looked at your code more thoroughly!, I found you are initialising state with [] it should be {} instead!!!